# Событие удаления элемента из RecyclerView

Tags: android

Удаляю элемент из `RecyclerView`.

```
items.remove(position);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, items.size());
```

`RecyclerView` находится во фрагменте. Можно ли как-то отловить удаление элемента в коде фрагмента?

P.S. `items` это `ArrayList` из объектов. `item` удаляется кнопкой на самом элементе.

Comment: у вас в массиве объекты класса хранятся или что-то более простое?

Comment: `items` это `ArrayList` из объектов.

Comment: а что именно вы хотите отловить и для чего?

Comment: Хочу отловить событие, когда удаляется элемент для того, чтобы выполнить некоторые дальнейшие действия уже во фрагменте.

Comment: ну можно попробовать вызывать функцию в фрагменте, но если честно не очень понял как вы не можете увидить удаление в фрагменте, если вы изначально должны удалять айтем из фрагмента

Comment: item удаляется кнопкой на самом элементе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91806/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-streletz).

Comment: Создайте колбэк для адаптера. Слушайте его во фрагменте, а метод дергайте при удалении элемента. При этом можете даже возвращать модельку элемента в колбэке, для дальнейшего отображения информации по удаленному элементу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете создать реализацию класса `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` и зарегистрировать ее в Вашем адаптере через метод `registerAdapterDataObserve`. В этом классе есть все методы которые Вам необходимы. И не забудьте отписаться методом `unregisterAdapterDataObserver`, когда Вам эта информация будет не нужна.

P.S. При удалении элемента в адаптере лучше сначала вызвать метод `notifyItemRemoved(position);` а потом уже `items.remove(position);` Тогда у вас отработает анимация удаления элемента.

Comment: Вот это как раз то, что я искал. Спасибо!